# jquery ajax not worked on my pc

Tags: ajax, jquery

I try to use AJAX get method on my PC .

My jquery version is 1.10 , and my problem detected when i move files from other system's localhost to my desktop .

I'm see the code do correct in other system localhost but when moved on my desktop not worked and show this error on google chrome :

```
OPTIONS file:///C:/Users/Ab3/Desktop/od/file3.htm Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery.min.js:6
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Ab3/Desktop/od/file3.htm. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. index.html:1
```

and in firefox not worked ,but don't show any error in fire bug.

my html code is :

```
        <button  class="tt" title="1" > btn1 </button>
        <button  class="tt" title="2" > btn2 </button>
        <button  class="tt" title="3" > btn3 </button>
        <div class="pop" id="popup">
            <div class="popup_close" id="pclose"></div>
        </div>
```

and my jquery code :

```
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $(".tt").click(function () {
                    var val = $(this).attr('title') ;
                    //alert(val);
                    $.get("file"+val+".htm",function (inp) {
                    alert(1);
                        $(".pop").html(inp);
                    });
                     $('#popup').show(300);
                });
                $('#pclose').click(function (){
                    $('#popup').hide(300);
               });
            });
```

and I'm sure file's file1.htm file2.htm  file3.htm exists.

how can i solve my pb.

Comment: You can't traverse the local file system through javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax is working on your computer, but not with url begining with `file://` because ajax needs to request the server to get a file. So, if you want to use ajax, you have to install a wamp server and move your files in.